# Numerically iterating the dynamics of a constrained Newtonian system

Tags: numerical-methods, classical-mechanics

This question is about the dynamics (in classical mechanics) of a rigidly linked chain of $N$ point masses, see figure. Let us say that the masses $m_1,\ldots,m_N$ have initial positions ($\mathbf{x}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{x}_N$) and initial velocities (velocities $\dot{\mathbf{x}}_1,\ldots,\dot{\mathbf{x}}_N$) are known and a homogeneous gravitational field is present. The lengths of the links between masses are rigid and must stay the same for all time. Given this information, we are able to compute the dynamics of the chain for all time.

How is it possible to numerically iterate the dynamics of the beads without fully describing the system as ODEs? I would like retain the ability to add/remove masses without changing without having to rewrite the Lagrangian and re-deriving the equations of motion. This includes changing the topology of the "chain" (by making loops like in the figure on the right).

Which numerical methods are used to iterate the dynamics without writing long Euler-Lagrange equations? For example, how do physics engines in games do it?

[image]

Comment: Once through your update loop and for each "step", just enumerate your masses and calculate the total force each mass feels from all other masses, using Newton's Law of gravitation.

Comment: The key question is how to implement the constraints (the lever length must remain constant, $\left(\mathbf{x}_{i}-\mathbf{x}_{j}\right)^{2}=\text{const}$). The gravitational field is homogeneous, e.g. $\mathbf{F}_{g}=-g\mathbf{e}_{z}$. The masses do not interact gravitationally among each other.

Comment: Ah, I missed the fact that the masses are linked. Sorry. I don't quite see how it can be done. It might help if you consider the first mass stationary, and then successively, update the positions of the rest of the masses, if you know all the velocities.

Comment: Looks like the section on Addition of angular velocity covers it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_velocity#Addition_of_angular_velocity_vectors

Comment: One approach might be to implement a high stiffness rod, rather than an infinite stiffness rod. Then derive the forces from gravity and tension and move the system a small amount. If that extends or contracts the rods a small amount then the stiffness adds a force to correct it in the next step. Getting the stiffness and time steps right might be tricky, but it should work

Comment: Note that if your links are rigid then perturbations should travel across your system infinitely fast. The easiest way to describe your system is a DAE
$$
\ddot {\mathbf{r}}_i = \sum_{j \in \text{neib } i} \gamma_{ij} (\mathbf r_i - \mathbf r_j) + \mathbf{g}\\
\gamma_{ij} = -\gamma_{ji}\\
(\mathbf r_i - \mathbf r_j)^2 = L_{ij}^2, j \in \text{neib } i
$$
with $\gamma_{ij}$ being unknowns to be derermined from constrains. At best that gives a system of linear equations in $\gamma_{ij}$ on each timestep (at worst - a system of nonlinear equations)